# Cannot import "odoo" & "PyPDF2"

Tags: python, odoo, pypdf

I have installed PyPDF2 in my virtual environment too.
[image: Installation of PyPDF2 in my Venv]

But When i check the status of my "odoo", It throws an error which says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyPDF2'"

[image: Status of "odoo" still results as failed!]

Any help will be heartly appreciated.

Comment: PyPDF2 is a python package and has to be installed with pip

Answer (score 1):

I think no need to install packages manually just run the odoo's standard requirements,txt situated along with odoo-bin file,

so run the `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0):

apt installs packages system-Wie. It will never install something in a virtual environment. You need to use

```
pip install PyPDF2
```

within the virtual environment